# Use complex exponential to find $n$th derivative of $\cos^2(ax)$

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I'm stuck. Any idea as to how I can continue?

$\cos(2ax) + i\sin(2ax) = e^{2iax}= (e^{iax})^2 = (\cos(ax)+i\sin(ax))^2$

Comment: Squaring you have $\cos(2ax) + i\sin(2ax) = \cos^2(ax)-\sin^2(ax)+2i \cos(ax)\sin(ax)$ but this has noting to do with the derivatives

Comment: I read this somewhere online...I found a pattern but couldn't figure out how to use complex exponential to solve it. Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have$$\cos^2(ax)=\left(\frac{e^{iax}+e^{-iax}}2\right)^2=\frac{e^{2iax}+2+e^{-2iax}}4.$$Therefore, the $n$<sup>th</sup> derivative od $\cos^2(ax)$ is$$\frac{(2ia)^ne^{2iax}+(-2ia)^ne^{-2iax}}4.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Got the first part, how do you transform it into the nth term? Sorry, I've only learnt this a few days ago.

Comment: @user567109 I just used the fact that the $n^\text{th}$ derivative of $e^{\lambda z}$ is $\lambda^ne^{\lambda z}$.

Comment: Understood, but why only differentiate the top and not the bottom?

Comment: Is right to say 1/4 (d^ny/dx^n)?

Comment: @user567109 $cf'(x)=f'(cx)$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$
\cos(a x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{i ax}+e^{-i a x}\right)
$$

we have

$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{i ax}+e^{-i a x}\right)\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\left(e^{2iax}+e^{-2iax}\right)
$$

Now deriving $e^{2iax}$...

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos^2ax=\frac{1+\cos 2ax}2$$
so that
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\cos^2ax=2^{n-1}a^n\cos(2ax+n\pi/2).$$
You could rewrite this as
$$\cos^2ax=\frac{2+e^{2iax}+e^{-2iax}}4$$
so that
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\cos^2ax=2^{n-2}i^na^n(e^{2iax}+(-1)^ne^{-2iax})$$
if you really, really want to use complex exponenials.